# why does powershell script skip to the end?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I've got a little Powershell script that is supposed to deploy some service fabric applications locally:

I'm attempting to execute it like this:

```
.\Deploy.ps1 -ArtifactPath C:\packages\EnterpriseAPIPackages201710109749b
```

For some reason it skips to the last line of the script!

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How do I get all the lines to execute?**

```
Param
(
    [String]
    $ArtifactPath
)

$LocalFolder = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$DeployScriptFile = "$LocalFolder\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1"

$ConfigFilePath = "$LocalFolder\config.xml"

$ConfigFilePath = Resolve-Path $ConfigFilePath

[Xml]$configParameters =  (Get-Content $ConfigFilePath)

$services = $configParameters.DeploymentConfiguration.Microservices

if (!$ArtifactPath)
{
    $ArtifactPath = $LocalFolder
}

$ApplicationPackageFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $ArtifactPath -Filter ApplicationManifest.xml -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach($ApplicationPackageFile in $ApplicationPackageFiles)
{
    $ApplicationPackagePath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $($ApplicationPackageFile.FullName)
    $ProjectName = Split-Path $ApplicationPackagePath -Leaf
    Write-Host "Start PowerShell script to deploy Microservice to Service Fabric: ApplicationPackageName: $($ProjectName)"

    $ScriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create("$DeployScriptFile -ApplicationPackagePath '$ApplicationPackagePath'")

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Debbuging? Is something in the $ApplicationPackageFiles variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong? How do I get all the lines to execute?

It seems there is nothing wrong with you code. I assume that there is nothing in the  `$ApplicationPackageFiles` variable, so the `foreach` clause is not be executed.

You debug it with one of the following ways:

1.Print the $ApplicationPackageFiles variable to console directly

```
 Write-Host "ApplicationPackageFiles value: $ApplicationPackageFiles"
```

2.Add the output info before and after `foreach` to check it.

```
Write-Host "Before loop..." 
foreach($ApplicationPackageFile in $ApplicationPackageFiles)
{
   xxxxx
}
Write-Host "After loop..."
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything immediately wrong with it. If you copy & pasted it from somewhere, the dashes, newlines, etc, might be wrong (especially if copy/pasting from rich text).

Open your script in PowerShell ISE or vscode and set a breakpoint at the top. Then you can step through line by line to narrow it down.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/05/use-the-powershell-debugger/